# How can I use Collectors instead of manually putting into ConcurrentHashMap in java 8

Tags: java, java-8

How can I Use Collectors to collect in a ConcurrentHashMap instread of putting manually into ConcurrentHashMap

```
ConcurrentHashMap<String, String> configurationMap = new ConcurrentHashMap<>();
List<Result> results = result.getResults();
results.stream().forEach(res -> {
     res.getSeries().stream().forEach(series -> {
         series.getValues().stream().forEach(vals ->{
                 configurationMap.put(vals.get(1).toString(),vals.get(2).toString());
         });
     });
});

//Note: vals is List<List<Object>> type
```

Help will be appreciated.

Comment: Use one of the overloads in Stream api https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/stream/Collectors.html#toConcurrentMap-java.util.function.Function-java.util.function.Function-

Comment: Think carefully whether this really has to be a `ConcurrentHashMap`. Apparently, this map is created once and only read afterwards. In that case, there is no need to use a `ConcurrentHashMap`; an ordinary `Map` would do as well.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

We can do this as follows also:

```
results.stream()
       .flatMap(res -> res.getSeries().stream())
       .flatMap(series -> series.getValues().stream())
       .collect(Collectors.toMap(
                              vals -> vals.get(1).toString(),
                              vals -> vals.get(2).toString(),
                              (vals1,vals2) -> vals2,
                              ConcurrentHashMap::new);
```

Answer (score 4):

You can use `Collectors.toConcurrentMap`

```
results.stream()
           .flatMap(res -> res.getSeries().stream())
           .flatMap(series -> series.getValues().stream())
           .collect(Collectors.toConcurrentMap(
                                  vals -> vals.get(1).toString(),
                                  vals -> vals.get(2).toString()));
```

Comment: You are missing some `flatMap()` calls, since `results` doesn't contain whatever `vals` is.

Comment: Normal code style has spaces around the `->`. Improves readability when common code styles are honored.

Comment: Note that `toConcurrentMap` returns, as the name suggests, a `ConcurrentMap`, not necessarily a `Concurrent` **`Hash`** `Map`…